# Extracting some charcter from string in java

Tags: java, split

How i can extract only img Url from below string in java.

```
<img src="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2014/b/bull_16-9_356x200_200_0558.jpg" alt="It may be too early to give up on bull market in equities" title="It may be too early to give up on bull market in equities" border="0" width="75" height="75" align=" left" hspace="5"
```

Comment: Use HTML parser or write your own.

Comment: Ok. You can get it. For single case, split and substring methods are your friends. Otherwise, follow @MarounMaroun

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String allContent = "<you url content>";
String rawUrl = allContent.split("http:")[1];
String partURL = rawUrl.split(".jpg")[0];           
String finalURL = "http:"+partURL+".jpg";
```

this is not the good way However it will work perfectly fine for your provided example.

Comment: This might create a bug factory. Don't do that on HTML, simply use a parser.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yup I agreed.

Answer (score 0):

What about a regex? `.*?src="([^"]+)".*` would capture all in src.

```
.*?src="([^"]+)".*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/m_hTqCU3cJ5uuReb)

For HTML or XML it would be better to use a real parser. If you have a very limited and specific input this might be enough though.

Comment: I using xmlPullParser but i am not getting.

Comment: Note that most html is not valid xml only xhtml would work with an xml parser. Better use an html parser like JSoup to parse HTML http://jsoup.org/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xmls its better to use parser and you have just string then you can use following code segement:

```
class imgUrl
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String tag="<img src=\"http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2014/b/bull_16-9_356x200_200_0558.jpg\" alt=\"It may be too early to give up on bull market in equities\" title=\"It may be too early to give up on bull market in equities\" border=\"0\" width=\"75\" height=\"75\" align=\" left\" hspace=\"5\"";
    String url=tag.substring(tag.indexOf("src=\"")+5, tag.indexOf("\"",tag.indexOf("src=\"")+5));
    System.out.println("Url is "+url);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that src can be also an attribute of script. If you are parsing an HTML source code, for sure you just don't have  element. So be careful to just target this element. This regex extracts what you need:

```
(.*?)<img(.*?) src=\"(.[^\"]*)\"(.*)
```